# Android Google Maps V2: Only Loads after zooming

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I just started programming my first Android app. However, even after thouroughfully following the Google Tutorial, including (!) getting a valid API key, the Google Maps doesn't load from the beginning (that means I can only see the grid).

The tiles are (weird?) only loaded after I use finger gestures (+- does not work) to adjust the zoom to a (random?) level. I don't have any idea on what could be the matter...once the first tile got loaded, the app works as expected.

I already worked through StackOverflow, the problem with everybody else was they were using MapView (V1).

I'm using

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

however...

Comment: maybe your connection is slow?

Comment: well I am running it with WLAN connected sitting right aside the router, DSL 16.000 should be enough for downloading the images though. I will try restarting the router

Comment: Are you doing anything else in your activity or are you just displaying the map at this point?

Comment: the map is also reacting to the orientation sensor updates